# Automatically Align Two Points in Powershell

Tags: powershell

When I leave one tab space, how can I ensure that the colon is evenly distributed on all lines? (I dont want to adding one more escape tab character)

**Sample Function**

```
Write-Output "dirs`t: helloworld `
optional`t: helloworld2"
```

**UnExpectedOutput**

```
dirs    : helloworld
optional        : helloworld2
```

**ExpectedOutput**

```
dirs    : helloworld
optional: helloworld2
```

> Some powershell functions can do this automatically as a **key : value**....
> Also, I try to do it without using any powershell built-in functions (format-list, convert/to/from ... etc.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the cmdlet [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list?view=powershell-7.3) with a [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3) to get your desired output :

```
[PSCustomObject]@{ dirs="helloworld"; optional="helloworld2" } | Format-List
```

Output :

```
dirs     : helloworld
optional : helloworld2
```

Comment: This covers just the output, to also cover the input, you might do this: ``[PSCustomObject]("dirs`t: helloworld `noptional`t: helloworld2" | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':') | Format-List``

Comment: What is the logic behind format list? Because I don't want to use any extra native powershell built in function, if u have any function for this can u share,

Comment: "*I don't want to use any extra native powershell*" ??? You asking a [tag:PowerShell] question, or? Sound like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to learn the algorithm in a native powershell command without using it, can't I? : ) It might sound a little interesting :)

Comment: PowerShell cmdlets are generally pretty (PS)object oriented (see: [PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject)), meaning that if you invoke (or pass) data from an external command (as your multiline string) you probably want to treat that as (a [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/l/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) stream as) PowerShell objects.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki that's always nice to dig and look what's under the hood! [have fun](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/FormatAndOutput/format-list/Format-List.cs) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a formatted string. This lets you specify placeholders for the values to be inserted later.

```
$format = "{0,-10}: {1}"

Write-Output ($format -f "dirs", "`thelloworld")
Write-Output ($format -f "optional","`thelloworld2")
```

[image]

Here are some other examples of formatted strings:

```
$name = "Alice"
$age = 25
"My name is {0} and I am {1} years old." -f $name, $age
```

The above code will parse to: "My name is Alice and I am 25 years old."

```
$pi = 3.14159
"Pi to two decimal places is {0:N2}." -f $pi
```

The above code will parse to: "Pi to two decimal places is 3.14."

```
$date = Get-Date
"Today's date in 'MM/dd/yyyy' format is {0:MM/dd/yyyy}." -f $date
```

The above code will parse to: "Today's date in 'MM/dd/yyyy' format is 2023/06/28."

Comment: `2023/06/28` is definitely not in `MM/dd/yyyy` format

Comment: {0,-10}, but it doesn't do it automatically :S

Answer (score 0):

[Cid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76576556/15339544) is absolutely the right one but looking at comments it seems you're interested in the logic being used by `Format-List` to lay down the object's properties and values as a List, so here is one way you can do it, essentially is very similar to [shadow2020's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76576999/15339544) but first getting the max padding needed.

```
$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{ dirs = 'helloworld'; optional = 'helloworld2' }
# Get the properties of the object
$properties = $obj.PSObject.Properties
# Get the Max Length of the property Names and add + 1
$padding = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Max(
    [string[]] $properties.Name,
    [System.Func[string, int]] { $args[0].Length }) + 1

# Now its a simple loop adding the max padding to each property Name
# and concatenating the semi-colon + property Value
foreach ($property in $properties) {
    $property.Name.PadRight($padding) + ': ' + $property.Value
}
```

Outputs:

```
dirs     : helloworld
optional : helloworld2
```

If you also want coloring like how `Format-List` does it you can insert [VT Escape Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
foreach ($property in $properties) {
    "$([char] 27)[32;1m" +              # Green Format Accent
    $property.Name.PadRight($padding) + # Property Name
    ":$([char] 27)[0m "  +              # Semi-colon + Reset VT
    $property.Value                     # Property Value
}
```